# Registered user First visit url displays flash message

Tags: laravel, middleware, flash-message

I would like to create middleware and check if registered user has already visited current URL and if not display flash message.
This feature i need just to show up tour on particular page so new user can understand what to do next.
I do realize that i can do it by store data in user table for each user but maybe there is another way to do such thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this for a single URL or there can be multiple urls?

Comment: @Abhishek I wanna show flash message for all url except landing page

Answer (score 0):

This may go quite complex depending on number of your routes. Why
    don't you just make it simple:

```
1. Whenever user signup just store a session say session()->put('show_tour', true);

2. Now, show the flash-message on every page for registered user by checking this session value.

3. Make a button to disable this tour in your flash message. Make an AJAX call to destroy this session.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Could you please explain to me a bit further ,when should I disable the tour ? As i do not know the way a user will go ,I can not destroy session in one url. What should I do?